# Null Pointer when trying to dynamically disable a preference

Tags: java, android

I am getting a null pointer exception on `mPreference = (Preference)...` in the following code (i.e. with debugger on, `mPreference` shows null; NB key is non-null, I can substitute with a literal and it still gives me the same exception):

```
public class SettingsManager extends PreferenceActivity {

    private Preference mPreference;
    private static boolean toggle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the XML preferences file
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    public void setPrefEnabled(Context context, String key, String enabled) {
        if (enabled.contentEquals("true")) {
            toggle = true;
        } else {
            toggle = false;
        }
        mPreference = (Preference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(key);
        mPreference.setEnabled(toggle);
    }
}
```

The class is being called by the following code, in the `applySettings` method of a class where `settingsManager` is instantiated in the constructor:

```
public class ConfigurationSetter {

    private static Context mContext;
    private static SettingsManager settingsManager;

    public ConfigurationSetter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        settingsManager = new SettingsManager();
    }

    private static void applySettings(Context context, String key,
            String value, String enabled) {
        settingsManager.setPrefEnabled(mContext, key, enabled);
    }
}
```

I've been scratching my head on this but may be a little too tired to figure it out on my own. Any help is appreciated.

Related to this problem, I [asked a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423709/are-intents-required-to-persist-preference-state-in-a-headless-activity) about whether intents are the required instantiater for this activity.

Comment: Is the NPE happening in the `getPreferenceScreen()` call or the `findPreference()` call? Are you sure `key` is non-null if `findPreference()` requires a non-null input?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I updated the post to respond to your quesitons

Comment: getPreferenceScreen() is probably returning null, you then try to call a method of this null.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate` method is never called in this code (and thus the `PreferenceScreen` is not filled during the call to `addPreferencesFromResource` as supposed). `onCreate` is a part of the `Activity` lifecycle which gets called if you launch your `Activity` using an `Intent`. One usually does not create Activities using `new`, as in that case they don't get linked to the proper `Context` and display other forms of undefined behaviour, like yours.